# Coverting an iPhone targeted app to Universal in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-universal-app

I have a project that was intended to be an iPhone app in first instance, but now I want it to also support iPad. I have changed project's target from iPhone to Universal, but I dont know how to manage both nib versions I need now, already having nibs designed for iPhone. I tried by loading same viewControllers with different nibs according to the device, but Im not allowed to set more than one interface control to the same outlets. Any help? I have Xcode 4.4

Comment: What do you mean by this `Im not allowed to set more than one interface control to the same outlets`?

Comment: That IBOutlet declared in .h can be only linked once...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy.
For your storyboard files, just include the `_iPad` and `_iPhone` suffixes.
For example, if the original storyboard name is `MyStoryboard.storyboard`, you'll now have `MyStoryboard_iPad.storyboard` and `MyStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard`. You can also set the storyboard file for each device under the summary view of the project.

Then, for the.xib files, include the `~iPhone` and `~iPad` suffixes. 
`ViewController.xib` becomes `ViewController~iPad.xib` and `ViewController~iPhone.xib`

To start off, you can just create a duplicate if your existing .xib files and rename them to have the iPad and iPhone suffixes. Then alter the contents of each .xib as needed.

As for the .m code, you can check device type and branch your code. My approach is to define macros that identify device type, like this:

```
#define isDeviceIPad (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define isDeviceIPhone (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

Then I just use these macros(which return bool values) to write code that's specific to a device type(such as placement or dimensions of a particular view etc.).

Comment: Thanks! What if I also need to apply some changes to ViewController's .m files? I'd also add iPhone/iPad suffixes?

Comment: You're welcome. The .m file is single and does not vary depending on device type. I've edited my answer to vary the .m code execution based on device type. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can change only targeted device as iPhone / iPad and you can use the `.xib` file of iPad:

```
  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    //For navigate to iphone view 
}
else{
     //For navigate to ipad view
}
```

[Reference](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 more XiB targeted for iPad to each file and during Navigation, select the Xib  after checking Device type with the code shown above